# SpriteSheet built with TexturePacker not loading in CCSpriteFrameCache

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x, sprite-sheet

I built a Sprite Sheet using TexturePacker and am then loading it in my app:

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile( "animation_s4.plist" );
```

But, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Cocos2d: cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file animation_s4.png as texture
Cocos2d: cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Couldn't load texture
```

This is in `Cocos2d-x` and `XCode` (but don't want to have the issue when I build the Android version too), but I cannot figure out why it can't load my texture. My sprite is a .png file.

**Does anyone know what could be the cause of this?**

Comment: Do you have both the `.plist` and the sprite sheet in your resources directory and being included in your target? I'm not sure what format you are using but I am using `.pvr.ccz`

Comment: @GameDeveloper Yes both files are in my resources directory. When I build for the Simulator I can navigate to the .app file and view everything I have in the package and the .plist and .png are correctly included. When you say included in my target, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Have you removed your `Derived Data` folder and/or dont a `clean` in your XCode project yet?

Comment: Looks like that worked. I had cleaned about 10 times and even restart XCode, but it finally stuck this time. Thanks!

Comment: of course. I created an answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rebuilding sprite sheets, adding/changing resources one should remove the `Derived Data` folder  to ensure that XCode starts from zero and pulls in fresh copies of all Resources.